# Link error with my own C++ library

Tags: c++, dynamic-library

This is my first time trying to make a simple library. I worked in Ubuntu 12.04 with g++ 4.6.3. Here is the problem:

```
[[mylib.cpp]]
#include<sqlite3.h>
void Mylib::blahblah() {...}
void Mylib::evenmoreblah() {...}
...

[[mylib.h]]
#include <...>
class Mylib {
    ...
};
```

Then I made the lib by:

```
 gcc -c -Wall -fpic mylib.cpp
 gcc -shared -o libmylib.so mylib.o
```

I used the library in a single test.cpp which contains only the main(). I put libmylib.so in ./libdir, and compiled by using:

```
 g++ -g test.cpp -o test -lpthread -L/usr/local/lib -lsqlite3 -L./libdir -lmylib
```

The error I got:

```
./libdir/libmylib.so: undefined reference to `sqlite3_close'
./libdir/libmylib.so: undefined reference to `sqlite3_exec'
./libdir/libmylib.so: undefined reference to `sqlite3_free'
./libdir/libmylib.so: undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could link `-lsqlite3` into your shared library with

```
 gcc -shared mylib.o -o libmylib.so -lsqlite3
```

<sup>If you do that, you don't need to explicitly link `-lsqlite3` to your program, but that won't harm.</sup>

and the order of linking arguments for your program is important:

```
 g++ -Wall -g test.cpp -o mytest \
   -L./libdir -lmylib -L/usr/local/lib -lsqlite3 -lpthread
```

it should go from higher-level libraries to lower-level (i.e. system) ones. And don't forget `-Wall` to get almost all warnings from the compiler, which is very useful.

Read the [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/).

PS. Don't call your program `test` which is a shell builtin (and the standard `/usr/bin/test`). Use some other name.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Your answer is as correct as zakinster's. But I would accept his since he replied a little bit earlier than you did. p.s. all the names in my example are fake, but thank you for pointing out that test is a shell builtin.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I can link sqlite3 when compile the library!

Answer (score 2):

If your library make references to sqlite3, you should link sqlite after linking your library :

```
g++ -g test.cpp -o test -lpthread -L/usr/local/lib -L./libdir -lmylib -lsqlite3
```

Otherwise `ld` won't find anything useful in libsqlite3 before linking your library and won't be able to find the requested symbols after that.

Answer (score 0):

Since your library uses `sqlite3`, you need to add that AFTER your own library in the linker command. I think you could add it to the linking of your shared library too, but not certain.

The linker resolves libraries and their references in the order you list them, so the order is important.