# making shared libraries, linux needs less arguments

Tags: linux, macos, gcc, shared-libraries

I have c++ file a.cpp, which uses references to libx.so.
a.cpp is made a shared library itself, liba.so by doing:

```
g++ -shared -fpic  a.cpp -o liba.so
```

This works fine under linux, yet in OSX, I'd need to readd the reference to x.so:

```
g++ -shared -fpic  a.cpp -o liba.so -L. -lx
```

or else:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "foo()", referenced from:
      bar()    in cctvRwlZ.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However in Linux if I wish to use liba.so, I also have to add libx.so on the command line, whereas in OSX I can get by, by merely including liba.so.

**Linux**

```
g++ main.cpp -L. -la -lx
```

*vs*

**OSX**

```
g++ main.cpp -L. -la
```

- Are these differences due to changes in executbale format, ELF vs Mach-O - could someone elaborate?
- Why is the exact order of dependents needed in the case of linux?

## Update

Looking at the libraries referenced:

### Mac

```
Darwin/liba.so:
    Darwin/liba.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    Darwin/libx.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)

Darwin/main:
    Darwin/liba.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
```

### Linux

```
ldd liba.so
    [none, besides default]

ldd a.out
    liba.so => /home/gandalf/BTSync/tutorials/cpp/sharedlibosx/liba.so (0x00007fcf89097000)
    libx.so => /home/gandalf/BTSync/tutorials/cpp/sharedlibosx/libx.so (0x00007fcf88a9f000)
```

So it shows nicely that linking for liba is deferred until it is actually used in something like a main.

Comment: nevermind the last question, it's been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with two-level namespaces, see:
http://archive.today/DeFLp

To mimic the "Linux-way" on OSX one would:

use -flat_namespace:

```
g++ -shared  -flat_namespace  -undefined warning -o liba.so a.o
```

and then use -flat_namespace in the main executable:

```
gcc main.cpp   -flat_namespace -o main  -L.  -la -lx
```

We can now also verify liba **and** libx are needed in main, instead of liba depending on libx

```
$ otool -L main
main:
    liba.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    libx.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
    /opt/local/lib/libgcc/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

And for liba:

```
otool -L liba.so
liba.so:
    liba.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libgcc/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.18.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
    /opt/local/lib/libgcc/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

### Sidenotes

Note that

```
gcc main.cpp   -flat_namespace -o main  -L.  -la #omission of libx
```

results in:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "foo()", referenced from:
      import-atom in liba.so
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

as in Linux, however also mind that omitting `-flat_namespace` **and** -lx does not give any warning until runtime:

```
$ gcc main.cpp  -o main  -L.  -la
$ main
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __Z3foov
  Referenced from: liba.so
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: __Z3foov
  Referenced from: liba.so
  Expected in: flat namespace

[1]    19297 trace trap  main
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, I don't know. `libx.so` is needed in both cases, so it presumably is included by default (`g++ -v ...` will tell the exact low-level commands used, that should answer that).

For the second part, the linker (invoked by `g++`, again `-v` gives blow-by-blow) processes the files *exactly in the order in which they are given*. As your `liba` needs symbols from `libx`, they must be processed in that order (the list of symbols to be satisfied is built up, and uses/defines are matched up as new libraries are seen; no "let's go back and recheck" ever).

Answer (score 0):

A shared library (like your `liba.so`) can be linked (on Linux) with another library (`libx.so` for you). Try `ldd liba.so` to find out. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19424604/841108) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16084914/841108).

Read [Drepper's paper: *How to write Shared Libraries*](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf); be aware of [VDSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO)...

Comment: Now I understand, by omitting (in my case) libx while compiling liba, the end executable has to figure it out, whereas:
`g++ -shared -fpic a.cpp -o liba.so -L. -lx` under linux would tie libx to liba.

this however does not explain why it does not work under OSX